# How to make a <nav> menu overlap the body of the page?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a page with multiple block sections and I'd like a menu from the header section to overlap the content in the body section. The thing is, my header `<div>` keeps making itself larger and that messes up my whole page. The menu I'm going for is a checkbox trick menu I learned to do during class.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: show us some of your code please. Perhaps you can make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Try to let the menu `position:absolute`. Post the code for a better help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the dropdown that is being shown, `position: absolute`. 
The header will be expanding because you are showing a relative item within it, thus making the container larger. By using `position: absolute;` you are taking the element out of the flow and so the container is not made larger.

[Demo without `position: absolute;`](https://jsfiddle.net/z5zdduh1/)

[Demo with `position: absolute;`](https://jsfiddle.net/7tLehvnz/)

In the second one you are setting the position of the absolute element:

```
input[type=checkbox] ~ nav {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
}
```

and then showing it if the checkbox is checked:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ nav {
  display: block;
}
```